# Flash external interface does nothing with javascript

Tags: java, flash, actionscript, externalinterface

My actionscript 2 code in my frame 1 (called main) is as follows:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.addCallback('getStr', getStr);

function getStr(): String {
   return "Hello World!";
}
```

And here is how my javascript code is trying to call it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function getStr() {
                var swf = document.getElementById("GETSTRSWF");
                var str = swf.gtStr();
                alert(str);
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href ="#" onclick="return getStr();">Get Str</a>
        <object id="GETSTRSWF" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="getStr.swf" width="0" height="0">
            <param name="movie" value="getStr.swf" />
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        </object>
    </body>

</html>
```

But I get this error, and it fails:

```
TypeError: swf.gtStr is not a function


var str = swf.gtStr();
```